# Scroll to a different section of page using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a page.vue with multiple sections and what I am trying to do is add a link to get that particular section on click. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help me find the issue. I have no experience with Vue.

```
<template>
 For more information, please <a @click="$vuetify.goTo('#about', options)">click</a>.
 <p>About section</p>
 <p :id="about">More information section</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your javascript. by using the `:` syntax before a property, you're actually using `v-bind`, so the expectation is that the right-hand assignment is a number, boolean, array, object or variable. Because `about` is a simple string, and not a variable, this won't work. Just remove the `:`

```
<p id="about">
```

Now it will work fine.